# Not properly retrieve cookie value from html(js) to php file

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

Okay, so, I've reached a point where my head is about to explode, so I thought someone might know what my problem is. I have a html form with select list. Now, on form submit, I want to set a cookie with the selected value from the select list (with javascript) and read it in the php file and use its value for another variable. When I select one of the options from the drop down and click submit, nothing changes, it's as if the same value is being passed.... I don't know where I am going wrong.

HTML + JS :

```
<form action="CalendarFeeder3.php" name="cf" method="post">
    <select name="myvalue" id="SelectTimeZone" name="cfd">
        <option value="Africa/Abidjan">Africa/Abidjan</option>
        <option value="Africa/Accra">Africa/Accra</option>
        <option value="Africa/Addis_Ababa">Africa/Addis_Ababa</option>
        <option value="Africa/Algiers">Africa/Algiers</option>
    </select>
<input type="submit" onClick="createCookie('cookieee',selectedValue,'500')">
```

The JS:

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
            if (days) {
                var date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
                var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
            }
            else var expires = "";
            document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/"+"; domain=.<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>";

            var selectedValue = document.getElementById("SelectTimeZone").value;
        }
```

And the PHP:

```
$kookie = $_COOKIE[_cookieee];
date_default_timezone_set($kookie);
```

Comment: `selectedValue` is going to be an undefined variable. You'd need `myvalue.selectValued` so it refers to the `<select>`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your browser to make sure the cookie is actually set?  I would do that next...

Lastly, I'd remove the path from the domain part of your cookie in the javascript.  A browser is going to try to match the domain it's browsing against that value, so the /fillerexample part may be tripping it up?

Answer (score 0):

is that the full html/js code ?

Because i don't see where you give a value to "selectedValue"

Also maybe the fact that the value 500 is passed as a string ? I can't recall how javascript handle that,  but i'm quite convinced it's not good.  try without the quote.

So, to sum up, try with :

```
onclick=" var sel = document.getElementById('SelectTimeZone'); createCookie('cookieee',sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value ,500); "
```

As for the PHP side,  i would go for `$kookie = $_COOKIE['cookieee'];`

And as suggested by marty, remove the domain part of your cookie.

Comment: tried all of your suggestions as well as Martys' , still nothing                             

Edit: the selectedValue is a variable that is set to the value from the list, its the last line of the js code,  var selectedValue = document.getElementById("SelectTimeZone").value;

Comment: did you notice that i put some bad double quotes instead of singles in my answer ? ( sorry, and i have edited now). If not, you may want to  retry. Also, Did you check your browser javascript console ( on firefox : Ctrl+Maj+j to get the console to open) for error messages ? those helps. The last line of your CreateCookie function  ( var selectedValue = document.getElementById("SelectTimeZone").value; ) does not do anything, as it assigns a value to a local variable just before returning (thus destroying the variable ).

Comment: add  `alert('selected value : ' + value);` as the first line of your CreateCookie function to check what the value that will be set really is.